# Cronjob of existing Pod

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin, openshift-enterprise

I have a django app running on Openshift 3.  I need to run certain manage.py commands on a regular basis.  In Openshift 2 I used the Cron gear and now in Openshift 3 I want to use the CronJob pod type.

I want to create a pod for the cronjob, use the same source as the django app is using, but not expose it.

For example:

W1 - Django app
D1 - Postgres DB

M1 - django app for manage.py jobs, run as a cronjob pod.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Just tried v3.6-alpha2 and same error :(

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a scheduled job.

- https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.5/dev_guide/cron_jobs.html
- https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/
- https://blog.openshift.com/openshift-jobs/

Note that at this time (OpenShift 3.5), you have to use `batch/v2alpha1` as the API version. Be careful of out of date documentation showing older version labels.

What I am not sure of is how you can easily reference the image associated with an existing imagestream produced when you used the S2I builder to build you application and you want to use the same image. The base Kubernetes object for this expects you to refer to the image from the image registry. You would thus need to work that out by looking at the imagestream and copying the image registry IP and image details over by hand.

---

UPDATE 1

See:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/45227960/128141

for details of how from OpenShift 3.6 you can have it resolve the imagestream name automatically. That mechanism is still alpha status in 3.6, but does work.

Comment: Right, so Graham, how can i get the same functionality that I have in OS2  I was able to get the CronJob job working with a specific reference to the internal registry and token, but that won't work in a general sense.

Comment: Confused by what you mean when you say "but that won't work in a general sense", also what specifically about OS2 functionality are you trying to replicate. Except for issues around reference to the image, the scheduled job should be able to do the same thing. If you don't want to use the image from the application which is already created, then use ``oc new-build`` to setup build of special image.

Comment: Graham, thanks for your continued interest in this.  Basically, I just need to run some django manage.py commands daily, and what I ultimately would want is a copy of the generated image from OS3 used in another pod.  I don't find an easy way to reference that in my YAML unless I use the whole IP+path+token to the generated image, and that doesn't seem to be the right way to do it, since it's very specific to the environment.  ideally, if i had an image called project/mydjangoapp:latest I would at most like to specify that, but can't

Comment: Apparently there may be changes coming in next OpenShift version (3.6) which simplifies this. Still trying to track down whether there is documentation yet for how it will work.

Comment: Graham, so i'm closer than before.  Is there a way to reference the local registry not by IP in the YAML?  I think the issue i run into is when i specify my image by <Project>/<application>:latest, it tries to pull from Docker.

Comment: I am not 100% sure what is name you can definitely use. Try ``docker-registry.default.svc.cluster.local``.

Comment: So, made major progress today, figured out how to get the Cron job JSON file implemented, then had to figure out it needed an APP_SCRIPT variable and then to let the image that S2I created run with those parameters and it worked!  I have a cron job now that runs and executes ```python manage.py``` and exits.  Simple, but it does what I want.  Now i'm trying to integrate the job portion into a template do i can know at creation time the name of the image

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten it to work with specifying the image name in the YAML, but then tried to get it to work as part of the template, but ran into an error when trying to use the batch/v1 version on this server

> Cannot create cron job "djangomanage". The API version batch/v1 for kind CronJob is not supported by this server.

My template code is

```
  - apiVersion: batch/v1
    kind: CronJob
    metadata:
      name: djangomanage
    spec:
      schedule: "*/5 * * * *"  
      jobTemplate:             
        spec:
          template:
            spec:
              containers:
              - name: djangomanage
                image: '${NAME}:latest'
                env:
                  - name: APP_SCRIPT
                    value: "/opt/app-root/src/cron.sh"
              restartPolicy: Never
```

CRON.SH

```
python /opt/app-root/src/manage.py
```

Comment: Try changing the ``apiVersion``. It may be still marked as a beta feature in the cluster you are using. See https://blog.openshift.com/openshift-jobs/

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton At this point Graham, i'm not seeing a way to import this cronjob via a template.  I've tried every way i know how, but each time it complains about the API / jobtype version.  If you can figure that out, it would be great.  Should I file an issue on the origin project?

Comment: Give me a chance to play with it today. Unfortunately the person who implemented most of the Job stuff is on holidays for a few weeks and I can't pester them.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton  Understood, and thank you so much for this.  I think it could be an important piece of the django sample app for OS, as cron and the manage.py extensions are heavily used.  Thanks again

Comment: So need to use ``batch/v2alpha1`` as shown in https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/ That at least is the correct version label.

Comment: Kubernetes issue tracking progression of CronJob to possible v1 version in Kubernetes 1.8 is https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/41039

Comment: Thanks Graham!  I'll watch it now.

Answer (score 0):

you need to update line 1 with this:

```
- apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
```

see link below:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.18/#cronjob-v1beta1-batch