# Openshift application lifecycle events - application creation event?

Tags: openshift

I'm trying to hook into an application created event in OpenShift - if such an event exists.

The reason being, I would like to have a command run (ideally in a new pod), for creating a database schema. It doesnt make sense to have this in the application image, as I only need this run once - when the application is created.
I have looked into pod lifecycle hooks (https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.1/dev_guide/deployments.html#pod-based-lifecycle-hook) however these events happen everytime there is a new deployment. So this also is too often for my use case.

Is there a way to have an image run just once when an Openshift application is created?

Comment: People still use lifecycle hooks for this, but would use a flag in a persistent volume, or check the contents of the database to determine if the first time initialisation of the database is required. The safest way though is to run the step manually if this is a permanent deployment.

Comment: Thanks, yes agree. Im also looking at using a Job (https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.5/dev_guide/jobs.html). It would be good if jobs could be part of templates.

Comment: They should be able to be created as part of a template. What are you trying to do that you think you can't have them in a template?

Comment: I havent tried adding a job to a template. But after reading the openshift docs on template objects, I didnt see mention of jobs, so assumed it wasnt possible.

Comment: The only non obvious thing around jobs is how you can have it refer to an image stream, rather than an image in an image registry as raw Kubernetes objects expect. For details on how to use an image stream reference see https://stackoverflow.com/a/45227960/128141

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track in the comments here. In the OpenShift v2 days the same scenario existed with lifecycle hooks.

For our WordPress Quickstart in OpenShift v2, for instance, we would check to see if the database was created yet on every new deployment. If not, we initialized an empty database with the same name as the app (in this case letting WordPress create the schema afterwards, but it's the same idea needed here): [OpenShift v2 WordPress deploy action hook](https://github.com/openshift-quickstart/wordpress-example/blob/master/.openshift/action_hooks/deploy#L95-L96)

In OpenShift v3, there are a few ways to implement a similar lifecycle hook, but the common pattern we're using in our templates now is to leverage the ability to execute a new pod to run database setup steps just prior to the deployment phase: [OpenShift v3 CakePHP pre deploy lifecycle hook](https://github.com/openshift/cakephp-ex/blob/e30618d730d039104bd27e8fbda248deeb1b9a00/openshift/templates/cakephp-mysql-persistent.json#L162-L167)

Following this pattern, you would add your code to generate your database schema in a file like the [v3 CakePHP migrate-database.sh](https://github.com/openshift/cakephp-ex/blob/e30618d730d039104bd27e8fbda248deeb1b9a00/migrate-database.sh) in your source repo and execute the script with a pre deploy lifecycle hook (via execNewPod), checking first to see if the database/schema (select * from someknowntable limit 1) exists before loading the schema.